# How to extract words and phrases using preg_split() in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need to extract the words and phrases within a text. For example, the text is:

Hello World, "Japan and China", Americans, Asians, "Jews and Christians", and semi-catholics, Jehovah's witnesses

Using preg_split(), it should return the following:

1. Hello
2. World
3. Japan and China
4. Americans
5. Asians
6. Jews and Christians
7. and
8. semi-catholics
9. Jehova's
10. witnesses

I need to know the RegEx for this to work (or is it possible?). Notice the rules, phrases are enclosed in quotes ("). Alphanumerics, single quotes (') and dashes (-) are considered part of the word (that's why "Jehova's" and "semi-catholics" are considered one word), the rest separated with spaces are considered as single words, while other symbols not mentioned are ignored

Comment: You can use `\S+` to make dashes and quotes considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do it very simply with str_getcsv like this:

```
// replace any comma or space by a singe space
$str = preg_replace('/(,+[ ]+)|([ ]+)/', ' ', $str);
// treat the input as CSV, the delimiters being spaces and enclusures double quotes
print_r(str_getcsv($str, ' ', '"'));
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => World
    [2] => Japan and China
    [3] => Americans
    [4] => Asians
    [5] => Jews and Christians
    [6] => and
    [7] => semi-catholics
    [8] => Jehovah's
    [9] => witnesses
)
```

Comment: But probably content of phrases should remain unaltered and this does changes them also. For instance, if you had the phrase "Jews, muslims and christians" it would be converted to "Jews muslims and christians".

Answer (score 0):

If your example string is typical, begin by dealing with the single and double quotes. I have used the [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php) here to make the string safe to work with.

```
$string = <<<TEST
Hello World, "Japan and China", Americans, Asians, "Jews and Christians", and semi-catholics, Jehovah's witnesses
TEST;
$safe_string = addslashes($string);//make the string safe to work with
$pieces = explode(",",$safe_string);//break into pieces on comma
$words_and_phrases = array();//initiate new array

foreach($pieces as $piece)://begin working with the pieces
    $piece = trim($piece);//a little clean up
    if(strpos($piece,'"'))://this is a phrase
        $words_and_phrases[] = str_replace('"','',stripslashes($piece));
    else://else, these are words
        $words = explode(" ",stripslashes($piece));
        $words_and_phrases = array_merge($words_and_phrases, $words);
    endif;
endforeach;
print_r($words_and_phrases);
```

Note: You could also use preg_replace, but it seems like overkill for something like this.